# Must width and Height of an image be defined when adding an Image to a Button

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I read some tutorials on building user controls in wpf before embarking on building my own.  Many of these centred around creating a control based on a standard button with the facility to add an imge and custom text.  Most of these also seemed to actively define the image dimensions and bind them to a dependency property so you might end up with xaml like this;

```
 <Button Background="#00000000" x:Name="MyBtn" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" ToolTip="Click me to do something." BorderThickness="0">
        <StackPanel Margin="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageName, ElementName=DN}"
                   Width="{Binding ImageWidth, ElementName=DN}"
                   Height="{Binding ImageHeight, ElementName=DN}"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding BtnText,ElementName=DN}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

Is it actually necessary to specifically define the Image Width and Height?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to but if you don't the image will just take its own height and width (or the whole available space, if it's inferior), which could be 1920x1080 and take the whole space.

**Edit on containers**

Most container will stretch it and make the image fill the whole space (according to the tiniest orientation). Some, like your StackPanel will only according to its Orientation property. A Canvas won't resize anything and the image will take its own size.

Comment: So if for example I know that the image (or images I might want to use are all 16 x16 then there would be no need to define a size they would render at 16 X !6 (assuming enough room in the control to do so) but if my images were say 256 x 256 and I wanted them rendered at 64 x 64 then defining the size would be necessary?

Comment: @DomSinclair It depends on what its container (Parent) is. Most container will stretch it and make the image fill the whole space (according to the tiniest orientation). Some, like your StackPanel will only according to its Orientation property. A Canvas won't resize anything and the image will take its own size.

Comment: Ah I see, so with xaml similar to that illustrated above the specific size definitions do definitely server a purpose.

Comment: @DomSinclair so specifying the size you want will guarantee your image will have this size (and truncate it if needed).

Comment: @DomSinclair note that it applies on all WPF elements, the container define how to measure and arrange its child(s) except if the child specify explicitely how it wants it